# Strange behaviour redirecting man pages

Tags: io-redirection, man

I wanted to redirect `mc`'s man page to a text file using `man mc > mc`, but I accidentally executed `man mc > mc grep`. What resulted was a text file named `mc` containing two concatenated `mc` man pages.

I then tried `man ls > 1 abc`, which resulted in text file named `1` containing the `ls` man page and an error message in the terminal: `No manual entry for abc`.

Next I tried `man du > du ls tac`. I expected three concatenated `du` man pages, but what actually resulted was a text file named `du` containing the man pages of `du`, `ls` and `tac` concatenated.

Why did each command produced the results it did?

Comment: In the first case, what was the resulting text file’s name? (Presumably `mc`...)

Comment: @Stephen Kitt: Yes, `mc`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the first finding  -  I get `mc` and `grep` in `mc`, which is to be expected.

Comment: I would expect `mc` and `grep` man pages in a file called `mc` for first example.

Comment: Hi EmmaV, I wondered if you would consider accepting my Answer? If you think it could use improvement in some way, please let me know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is consistent with a relatively obscure part of the Bash manual, which states under the section *Shell Grammar*:

> A  simple  command  is  a sequence of optional variable assignments followed by blank-separated words **and redirections**, and terminated by a control operator.  The
>          first word specifies the command to be executed, and is passed as argument zero.  The remaining words are passed as arguments to the invoked command.

(Emphasis mine.)

What that means is that you can "mix" any redirections in with the command and its arguments.

For example, `echo > world hello` is equivalent to `echo hello > world`.

In other words, when you run a command like `man du > du ls tac`, it is equivalent to running:

```
man du ls tac > du
```

That these three manpages all end up concatenated into a file named `du` is then the result of how `man` behaves when its output is being redirected or piped: it will no longer try to use a pager and will essentially act like `cat`.

Answer (score 0):

Only for reference/curiosity:

I know I'm not answering your question but in case you need to redirect the content of a man page you can do it with col(1)

`man 1 col | col -b -x > manfile.foo`