# Join two files based on a common field

Tags: text-processing, join

I'm trying to join two files together based on their common field, and output it to a file, using the `join` command.

**File 1:**

```
C01:Nancy:Jones:njones@abc.com 
C02:Barbara:Madison:bmadison@bcd.com 
C03:Tim:Adams:tadams@cde.com
C04:Sarah:Moore:smoore@def.com
C05:John:Polk:jpolk@efg.com
C06:Paula:Jacobs:pjacobs@fgh.com
```

**File 2:**

```
R001:07/04/15:123.45:C01
R002:12/20/15:167.50:C03
R003:03/14/16:298.00:C06
R005:09/15/16:36.50:C03
R005:11/27/16:58.00:C02
R006:02/28/17:72.98:C05
```

**Expected Output**

```
C01:Nancy:Jones:njones@abc.com:R001:07/04/15:123.45
C02:Barbara:Madison:bmadison@bcd.com:R005:11/27/16:58.00
C03:Tim:Adams:tadams@cde.com:R002:12/20/15:167.50
C03:Tim:Adams:tadams@cde.com:R004:09/15/16:36.5
C05:John:Polk:jpolk@efg.com:R006:02/28/17:72.9
C06:Paula:Jacobs:pjacobs@fgh.com:R003:03/14/16:298.00
```

I've tried sorting `File2` based on field 4 first and then outputting it to a new file

```
sort -t: -k 4 File2 > File22
```

then joining

```
join -t: -1 1 -2 4 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.1 2.2 2.3' File1 File22 > File 3
```

but I always get a blank output file. I'm also not sure how to handle the omission of *row 4* from `File1` and the fact that `C03` comes up twice in `File2`.

Comment: Nicely worded question: example input, expected output, demonstration of attempts to solve the problem yourself. +1

Comment: Your code works fine here, it produces the expected output. Are you working with dos files or unix files ?

Comment: @don_crissti Not here. Since `File 3` is not surrounded by quotation marks I get an error `join: extra operand '3'`; and an empty file named `File` is created. Furthermore, when I run the command without redirection, the records for `C04` and `C05` are missing from the output, whereas Jim has stated they should appear in the output.

Comment: @cryptarch - I assume `File 3` is a typo and the OP meant `File3` (or whatever the real name of the file is). There is no mention of an error in the post. As to the records missing, only `C04` is missing from the output here - _which is correct_, according to the "Expected output" posted by the OP. As I said, I get the exact output that is expected. I'm not sure how to read the part that says _"how to handle the omission of row 4 from File1 and the fact that C03 comes up twice in File2"_ maybe the OP can elaborate on that...

Comment: @don_crissti Yeah the File 3 was a typo meant File3. To clarify what you're saying, when you ran this using those two files you got the expected output? I created both files in the vi editor, i'll go back over them, maybe I mistyped something.

Comment: I just copied-pasted from your post and ran your commands. Actually, I golfed it shorter using process substitution as in `join -t: -1 1 -2 4 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.1 2.2 2.3' file1 <(sort -t: -k 4 file2)` which produces the exact output that was requested.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you need to do to get things working the way you want. First of all, by appending `> File 3` to the end of the command, you are redirecting the output to `File` and also adding the extra argument `3` to the `join` command.

To explain why this happens, I recently (and coincidentally!) answered a similar question at [Strange behaviour redirecting man pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490621/strange-behaviour-redirecting-man-pages/490626#490626). Basically, it has to do with Bash grammar, which you can read more about in `man bash`.

To fix that behaviour, you should either ensure there are no spaces in the output file, or you should escape the space, or you should surround the filename with quotation marks. Any of the following redirections would work:

```
... > File3
... > File\ 3
... > "File 3"
```

Now to address the missing records from the output. This is handled by the `-a` flag. From `man join`:

> ```
> -a FILENUM
>        also print unpairable lines from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1 or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2
> ```

Putting it all together, the following command works for me (I will use `tee` rather than a redirection to show the output):

```
$ join -t: -1 1 -2 4 -o '1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 2.1 2.2 2.3' -a 1 File1 <(sort -t: -k4 File2) | tee "File 3"
C01:Nancy:Jones:njones@abc.com :R001:07/04/15:123.45
C02:Barbara:Madison:bmadison@bcd.com :R005:11/27/16:58.00
C03:Tim:Adams:tadams@cde.com:R002:12/20/15:167.50
C03:Tim:Adams:tadams@cde.com:R005:09/15/16:36.50
C04:Sarah:Moore:smoore@def.com:::
C05:John:Polk:jpolk@efg.com:::
C06:Paula:Jacobs:pjacobs@fgh.com:R003:03/14/16:298.00
```

Answer (score 0):

with Miller http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/reference.html the command is

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output --fs ":" join --ul -l 4 -r 1 -j 4 --lp l --rp r -f file2.csv file1.csv
```

And you have

```
C01:R001:07/04/15:123.45:Nancy:Jones:njones@abc.com
C02:R005:11/27/16:58.00:Barbara:Madison:bmadison@bcd.com
C03:R002:12/20/15:167.50:Tim:Adams:tadams@cde.com
C03:R005:09/15/16:36.50:Tim:Adams:tadams@cde.com
C05:R006:02/28/17:72.98:John:Polk:jpolk@efg.com
C06:R003:03/14/16:298.00:Paula:Jacobs:pjacobs@fgh.com
```